# Simulating Rails form submit in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a pretty standard Rails HAML new object form that does the usual stuff and ends with:

```
= f.submit "Add scenario"
```

This works perfectly, and the `scenarios_controller.rb` is also a straightforward:

```
def create
  ...create scenario...
  redirect_to scenarios_path
end
```

However, I have also developed a wizard-type form that needs to do some JavaScript on pressing my button:

```
= f.submit "Add scenario", :onclick => "return validateForm()"
```

In my CoffeeScript, I collect up all the information and finish up with:

```
$.post(
  url
  data
  (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
    # How do I follow the redirect?
return false
```

My `url` and `data` are correct as the above controller works correctly and creates my object, but my page doesn't redirect to `scenarios_path`. I think I should be doing something with the post result, but searching around the web I cannot find out what, and examining the returned fields in Chrome's debugger doesn't suggest anything. The only suggestion I saw was to use `data.redirect`, but such a field doesn't exist, although `jqXHR.responseText` seems to contain the page I want to redirect to.

Comment: You can redirect using javascript with `window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";`

Comment: @cantonic I wanted to avoid that as my page takes a little time to render, so doing it twice seems a bit of a waste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd treat the HTML call to `Scenario#create` and the JS call to `Scenario#create` differently, using a respond_to block.

In your `scenarios_controller.rb` file:

```
def create
  # create your object
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      redirect_to scenarios_path
    end
    format.js
  end
end
```

In `views/layouts/scenarios/create.js.erb`, then put something like:

```
window.location.replace("<%= scenarios_path %>");
```

When you call `Scenario#create` with JS, the `create.js.erb` file gets rendered and forces the redirect. When you call `Scenario#create` with HTML, the `redirect_to` call happens as usual.

Comment: Great, that fixes the problem - the `format.js` was the magic I was missing.